# How to parse XML from pre tags in php?

Tags: php, xml

I am getting a response from curl something like this

```
<pre>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
\t&lt;ksiazka kod=&quot;WKSPA4&quot; id=&quot;1168&quot;&gt;
\t\t&lt;dzien data=&quot;2020-12-22&quot;&gt;1&lt;/dzien&gt;
\t&lt;/ksiazka&gt;
```

How can I parse it and read as normal XML in php?

My code looks like:

```php
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do some basic string manipulation to remove the junk and then load into DOMDocument,

```
$str='<pre>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
    \t&lt;ksiazka kod=&quot;WKSPA4&quot; id=&quot;1168&quot;&gt;
    \t\t&lt;dzien data=&quot;2020-12-22&quot;&gt;30&lt;/dzien&gt;
    \t&lt;/ksiazka&gt;';
    
$xml=str_replace( array('\t','<pre>'), '', html_entity_decode($str) );
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $xml );
/* do other fudgery here if desired... */
printf('<textarea cols=80 rows=10>%s</textarea>',$dom->saveXML());
```

Which yields:
[image: example output]

Answer (score 0):

I personally like [Symfony DomCrawler Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) Component to do such jobs